# Pandas - How to make sure if a dataframe is missing some columns they are just created and set to null?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below df columns in a list that I use below to make sure to add the columns are in the correct order:

```
import pandas as pd

column_header = ['blast_id', 'labels', 'name', 'subject', 'list', 'mode', 'copy_template', 'stats',
                          'start_time', 'modify_time', 'schedule_time', 'email_count']


df = df[column_header]
```

but the df is missing some values like `labels` and `name`, etc. How do I make sure that if any of the columns from `column_header` are missing that we just add that column in and have null values?

Comment: You can `reindex` the dataframe along the column axis: `df.reindex(columns=column_header)`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
   copy_template  list  modify_time  blast_id  name  stats  mode
0              1     1            1         1     1      1     1
1              2     2            2         2     2      2     2
```

You need to `reindex`:

```
column_header = ['blast_id', 'labels', 'name', 'subject', 'list', 'mode', 'copy_template', 'stats',
                          'start_time', 'modify_time', 'schedule_time', 'email_count']

df.reindex(columns=column_header)
```

output:

```
   blast_id  labels  name  subject  list  mode  copy_template  stats  start_time  modify_time  schedule_time  email_count
0         1     NaN     1      NaN     1     1              1      1         NaN            1            NaN          NaN
1         2     NaN     2      NaN     2     2              2      2         NaN            2            NaN          NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for any  missing columns and then set them to Nan for all rows:

```py
# identify any cols that we don't have
missing_cols = [
    col for col in df.columns 
    if col not in set(column_header)
]

# fill in each one with nan
for col in missing_cols:
    df[col] = pd.np.nan

df[column_header]
```

or in a really short piece of code:

```py
for col in column_header:
    if col not in df.columns: 
        df[col] = pd.np.nan
```

Comment: `pd.np` is obsolete. Just use `np`

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
df[pd.Index(column_header).difference(df.columns)] = np.nan
```

To make sure the columns are all in the proper order, do this instead:

```
missing = pd.Index(column_header).difference(df.columns)
df[missing] = np.nan
df = df[column_header]
```